# Implementing Oauth Server with Authorization Code grant

Tags: web, oauth, oauth-2.0

A bit naive question. I am implementing OAuth server 2.0 with grant type = Authorization code grant. Here's what I have done

1) Created 2 endpoints as **/login** and **/token**

2) Created a login page with html as

```
<html>
     <form action=\"/login\" method=\"post\">

     <div class=\"textcontainer\">
          <label><b>Sign in</b></label>
     </div>
     <div class=\"emailcontainer\">
          <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Enter email\" 
           name=\"uname\" required>
     </div>

     <div class=\"passwordcontainer\">
          <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Enter Password\" 
             name=\"psw\" required>
     </div>

     <div class=\"signincontainer\">  
           <button type=\"submit\">Sign in</button>
           <input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\"> Remember me
     </div>

     <div class=\"container\" style=\"background-color:#f1f1f1\">
        <span class=\"psw\">Forgot <a href=\"#\">password?</a></span>
     </div>
   </form>
```

3) The above page will be displayed when client sends

> GET
>   /login?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE_STRING&scope=REQUESTED_SCOPES&response_type=code

4) I will save the state and redirect URI and the html page is displayed.

5) When user enters email and password and clicks submit button, then a POST will be issued to my server as **POST /login** and I will fetch the email and password from the request and verify.

Now the problem is I am not able to figure out a way to know if this POST has come from the same client who has called the previous GET.

Is there any way/html trick I can do to **resend** the **state** again in my submit button post? Is saving client IP the only way?

I understand the **POST /token** so that part is clear.

Thanks
Sammy

Comment: do you absolutely have to implement your own server?

Comment: Yes I need to implement my own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a unique identifier (GUID) on the server, before sending the form.
Then put it into the form inside a hidden input :

```
<form>
    ... your code

    <input type="hidden" value= "<%= <your identifier> %>">
</form>
```

Then this unique value will be returned to you in the `POST`.

the way you insert the identifier depends on your programming language, I used C# an the above example.

Comment: thanks Alex, this way state itself can be used as a hidden parameter.